# ReviewBoard on Windows throwing error 207 when trying to create a review

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, bitnami, review-board

I am trying in Mercurial with the `hgreviewboard` extension, to create a working review, like this:

```
C:\dev\test>hg postreview tip

Changeset 2:938259978c8e
---------------------------
A sample change to be code reviewed.

reviewboard:    http://myreviewboard.mysite.com:8081/reviewboard

username: warren
password: **********
Looking for 'myreviewboard.mysite.com /reviewboard/' cookie in C:\Users\userid\A
ppData\Roaming\.post-review-cookies.txt
Loaded valid cookie -- no login required
abort: The file was not found in the repository (207)
stat: fail
file: test.txt
revision: 66bd323b0a11
```

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248865/mercurial-reviewboard-and-post-review/13340940#13340940) I am trying to use ReviewBoard 1.7.9 which I installed using the Bitnami installer, on Windows.  I am trying to use it with mercurial. The first challege is that the bitnami install doesn't include the `mercurial` site-package files in its installation, so once that's remedied, I get stuck where dozens of others seem to get stuck, and I am wondering if my problem is one of the problems that has lead ReviewBoard devs to state that [they don't recommend or support running ReviewBoard version 1.7 on Windows.](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/installation/windows/)

It seems that whoever packages the upstream bitnami stacks doesn't agree, and has kept right on packaging Bitnami ReviewBoard version 1.7.x versions.

Has anyone got ReviewBoard 1.7.9 working on Windows, with mercurial? Note that above I'm showing you a command line prompt in Windows, but the server-side is also running on Windows, thanks to Bitnami installers for Windows.

Comment: I think I figured it out;  `getaddrinfo` is failing but you can't see that unless you enable the server-logging feature from the Admin console and put it into Debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that DNS or getaddrinfo calls were failing to resolve myreviewboard.mysite.com

It really helps to enable the logging features in Reviewboard and set their output to Debug level of verbosity, when Reviewboard is doing something wonky.

At another question here on Stackoverflow, it was recommended that ReviewBoard may not be able to read certain mercurial repository versions and that a clean clone (`hg clone -U oldrepo newrepo`) is required in order to get it to work in ReviewBoard. I'm including that tip here in case it's not some other thing.

But basically without the debug logs on the server side, a client-side error # 207 is impossible to debug.